# Renaming all feature classes in file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I have 8 separate geodatabases in which are contained tiled feature classes all of the same name e.g. TopographicArea. So that each of my File Geodatabases contain a feature class called TopgraphicArea etc..

I would like to be able to merge the feature classes from each geodatabase of the same type (e.g all feature classes called TopgraphicArea etc..) but as it stands I can't because the names are identical.

How can I rename, or append a suffix to, each feature class so that they can subsequently be merged?

Ideally I'd like the feature classes in gdb1 to be "1" in gdb2 to be "2" and so on and preferably to be done in ModelBuilder.

Comment: By "merge", do you mean copying featureclasses to an output geodb such that gdb/TopographicArea1, gdb/TopographicArea2... are copies of the featureclasses gdb1/TopographicArea, gdb2/TopographicArea ?

Comment: Since you are only dealing with 8 geodatabases, and thus, 8 feature classes, it almost seems like this is making it more complicated than it needs to be.  I don't mean that to be condescending because I get caught in the same trap.  I try to automate something, when the reality is that simply doing it by hand is just as fast.  In this case, I mean going in through ArcCatalog, right-clicking each feature class and renaming it.
If there is a reason this won't work, definitely please modify your question to add some more detail.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126452/using-python-to-rename-feature-class-by-field-arcmap) question? You could adapt that code and put it in the python console in arcmap..

Comment: @GetSpatial you're totally right, I just feel like it's something I SHOULD be doing in an automated way.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall yes an output .gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is pretty simple, but it should work for what you want to do.  Again, in the time it took to write the code, you could rename the featureclasses by yourself, but the logic works if you need to scale it up to a larger number.

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set Output Geodatabase Name
outgdb = "C:/workspace/outfc.gdb"

#Set Range to cycle Through
for num in range(1,8):
  #Set workspace to gdb name and iterator number
  env.workspace = "C:/workspace/gdb" + num + ".gdb"
  #List featureclasses in that workspace
  fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
  #Iterate through featureclasses
  for fc in fclist:
    oldnm = fc
    #Rename featureclasses to old name plus iterator
    newnm = fc + num
    arcpy.Rename_management(oldnm, newnm, "FeatureClass")
    #Copy renamed featureclasses into Output Geodatabase
    newloc = outgdb + os.sep + newnm
    arcpy.Copy_management(newnm, newloc, "")
```

Comment: Python is pretty easy with mashing types together.  I've done similar before with no problems.

Comment: Perfect, I renamed them manually yesterday  but wanted to test the logic as it's something that'll have to be repeated and possibly with more GDBs and this worked perfectly - many thanks.